# Kafka-console-producer returns topic timeout error

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, producer-consumer, consumer, producer

I'm trying to produce message using kafka-console-producer. but end up with the following error.

```
$ /usr/bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list confluent-kafka-0-service.ms-kafka-internal.svc:9092 --topic testTopic --producer.config ~/etc/kafka/client_security.properties
```

[2020-08-09 06:37:52,844] INFO Kafka version: 5.4.2-ccs (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2020-08-09 06:37:52,845] INFO Kafka commitId: 2626d8cfb686c23e (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2020-08-09 06:37:52,845] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1596955072646 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)

> Hi
> Welcome to Confluent Kafka
> [2020-08-09 06:38:55,451] **ERROR Error when sending message to topic testTopic with key: null, value: 2 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic testTopic not present in metadata after 60000 ms.**

I have run the below consumer command to see the messages. But then also no messages have been seen.

```
/usr/bin/kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server confluent-kafka-0-service.ms-kafka-internal.svc:9092 --topic testTopic --from-beginning --consumer.config ~/etc/bmw/kafka/client_security.properties
```

Any immediate help would much appreciated.

Thanks,
Mina

Answer (score 0):

Note that your producer and consumer points to different paths:

--consumer.config ~/etc/**bmw**/kafka/client_security.properties

vs

--producer.config ~/etc/kafka/client_security.propertie

maybe you just got the wrong config file path?

Comment: Hi Oleg Thanks for the response.   Below Commands im using.
But then ended here with this error: After Producer command:
I have no name!@confluent-kafka-0:/$ kafka-console-producer --broker-list confluent-kafka-0-service.ms-kafka-internal.svc:9092 --topic testTopic --producer.config ~/etc/bmw/kafka/client_security.properties
ERROR Error when sending message to topic testTopic with key: null, value: 6 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic testTopic not present in metadata after 60000 ms.

Comment: Hi Mina, can you try to ping the Kafka brokers? can you also share the command that created the 'testTopic' that you are using?

Comment: Hi, Im using Confluent Kafka on Openshift where i dont have option to ping or ssh to brokers. Outside Openshift, i use oc commands. Below is the command i used for Topic creation: kafka-topics --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 3 --topic testTopic

Comment: so the Zookeeper runs locally on your machine but the Kafka brokers runs on Openshift?

Comment: No. Zookeeper also in same openshift namespace.

Comment: In order for this to work you need to have the ability to access those hosts (and ports) from the machine you are trying to run the console producer from. If your Kafka brokers sits in an environment which is not accessible from your host you can alway try to ssh to a container and try it from there. but first make sure you have a ping to those brokers.

Comment: Im running my commands inside the Openshift and in Kafka pods. Whee both the Kafka and Zookeeper are in same place. Im facing issue basically with Kafka clients. Am i missing anything in the Config part which causes this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
This is the entire Content of Producer command.
I have no name!@confluent-kafka-0:/$ kafka-console-producer --broker-list confluent-kafka-0-service.ms-kafka-internal.svc:9092 --topic testTopic --producer.config ~/etc/bmw/kafka/client_security.properties
[2020-08-10 09:46:00,186] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2020-08-10 09:46:03,389] INFO ProducerConfig values:
        acks = 1
        batch.size = 16384
        bootstrap.servers = [confluent-kafka-0-service.ms-kafka-internal.svc:9092]
        buffer.memory = 33554432
        client.dns.lookup = default
        client.id = console-producer
        compression.type = none
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
        enable.idempotence = false
        interceptor.classes = []
        key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
        linger.ms = 1000
        max.block.ms = 60000
        max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
        max.request.size = 1048576
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
        receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 1500
        retries = 3
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        security.protocol = SSL
        security.providers = null
        send.buffer.bytes = 102400
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.key.password = [hidden]
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = /etc/bmw/kafka/client_certs/kafka-client-internal-keystore.jks
        ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = /etc/bmw/kafka/bmw_certs/bmw-truststore.jks
        ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
        transactional.id = null
        value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
 (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig)
[2020-08-10 09:46:11,786] INFO Kafka version: 5.4.2-ccs (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2020-08-10 09:46:11,786] INFO Kafka commitId: 2626d8cfb686c23e (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2020-08-10 09:46:11,786] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1597052771592 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
>Om namo Narayanaya nama
Jai Sri ram
[2020-08-10 09:47:21,186] ERROR Error when sending message to topic testTopic with key: null, value: 23 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic testTopic not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
>^C[2020-08-10 09:47:25,485] INFO [Producer clientId=console-producer] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Producer closed while send in progress
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:888)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:865)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.send(ConsoleProducer.scala:75)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.main(ConsoleProducer.scala:57)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer.main(ConsoleProducer.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Requested metadata update after close
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerMetadata.awaitUpdate(ProducerMetadata.java:104)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.waitOnMetadata(KafkaProducer.java:1029)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:885)`

Thanks,
Mina
```